# How to extract a specific column from a different workbook stored in a folder using VBA?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, microsoft-excel-2007

Suppose I have workbooks and each workbook contain single worksheets and all worksheets have same number of rows and columns..from each worksheet ..I want to extract a column name "May 10-11" . This column name is common to each worksheet..so how can I extract a column "May 10-11" from each workbook stored in same folder..

for example :
[image: data matrix . this image is just a sample of data]

Each worksheet contain same number of rows and columns, rows = 453 and columns= 55 ..from this sample image i want to extract " may 10-11" column from all the workbooks stored in same folder and stored in different worksheet..

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please note that [SU] is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19351832/copy-from-one-workbook-and-paste-into-another

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want? source is from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg549168(v=office.14).aspx

```
Sub MergeAllWorkbooks()
    Dim SummarySheet As Worksheet
    Dim FolderPath As String
    Dim NRow As Long
    Dim FileName As String
    Dim WorkBk As Workbook
    Dim SourceRange As Range
    Dim DestRange As Range

    ' Create a new workbook and set a variable to the first sheet. 
    Set SummarySheet = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet).Worksheets(1)

    ' Modify this folder path to point to the files you want to use.
    FolderPath = "C:\Users\Peter\invoices\"

    ' NRow keeps track of where to insert new rows in the destination workbook.
    NRow = 1

    ' Call Dir the first time, pointing it to all Excel files in the folder path.
    FileName = Dir(FolderPath & "*.xl*")

    ' Loop until Dir returns an empty string.
    Do While FileName <> ""
        ' Open a workbook in the folder
        Set WorkBk = Workbooks.Open(FolderPath & FileName)

        ' Set the cell in column A to be the file name.
        SummarySheet.Range("A" & NRow).Value = FileName

        ' Set the source range to be A9 through C9.
        ' Modify this range for your workbooks. 
        ' It can span multiple rows.
        Set SourceRange = WorkBk.Worksheets(1).Range("A9:C9")

        ' Set the destination range to start at column B and 
        ' be the same size as the source range.
        Set DestRange = SummarySheet.Range("B" & NRow)
        Set DestRange = DestRange.Resize(SourceRange.Rows.Count, _
           SourceRange.Columns.Count)

        ' Copy over the values from the source to the destination.
        DestRange.Value = SourceRange.Value

        ' Increase NRow so that we know where to copy data next.
        NRow = NRow + DestRange.Rows.Count

        ' Close the source workbook without saving changes.
        WorkBk.Close savechanges:=False

        ' Use Dir to get the next file name.
        FileName = Dir()
    Loop

    ' Call AutoFit on the destination sheet so that all 
    ' data is readable.
    SummarySheet.Columns.AutoFit
End Sub
```